# Global Liquid Variable not working in JS file

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

I'am currently building a upsell section in the ajax cart (Brooklyn Theme).
I need the **variant.id** of a product in my **js file**** but have no idea how to do it. I tried everything I know.

**That's the code that works in every other file (except the js file):**

```
{%- assign product = all_products[settings.upsell_product] -%}

{{ product.variants[0].id }}
```

The funny thing is that **the following code works, even in the js file**

`{{ settings.upsell_headline }}`

Thats my settings_scheme.json file code:

```
      {
        "type": "header",
        "content": {
          "de": "Cart Upsell"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "text",
        "id": "upsell_headline",
        "label": {
          "de": "Headline"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "product",
        "id": "upsell_product",
        "label": {
          "de": "Upsell Product"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

Comment: is it a `js` file or a `liquid` file that you are using?

Comment: its the theme.js.liquid file

Answer (score 0):

don't add code to the `theme.js.liquid`

`settings_scheme.json` hold information about the theme.  All global data should be stored in `settings_data.json`.  In addition to that, the data is generated automatically from `section` when users customize the theme.

https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/settings#basic-input-setting-types

what you should do is,  create a section called `upsell-product.liquid`, put the `json` there.

```
<script>
  {%- assign product = all_products[section.settings.upsell_product] -%}

  $(document).ready(function(){
    console.log({{ product.variants[0].id }});
  });
</script>

{% schema %}
{   
  "name" : "upsell product",
  "settings" : [
    {
      "type" : "text",
      "id" : "headline",
      "label" : "headline",
      "default" : "headLine"
    },
     {
    "type": "product",
    "id": "upsell_product",
    "label": {
      "de": "Upsell Product"
    }
  ]  
}
{% endschema %}
```